# Rectify curved text with Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

Any tools in Photoshop CS3 to rectify a circle curved text so that it will be suitable for OCR after that?[image]

I tried Wrap and Skew, but it consumes too much time and result is far from decent.

Comment: Given that (1) it would be a laborious project, and (2) whatever OCR you are going to use on this, it'll most likely still won't recognize all of the text correctly, and (3) the image is quite sharp, I'd just type it in. It's just 3 lines of text. (Okay, long ones.)

Comment: @Jongware: There isn't just one image. I could write a software for that, but am interested in PS capabilities.

Comment: I'm wondering (not having Photoshop right now to test) if Polar to Rectangular (or reverse), may help, potentially adjusting the size of the image (adding transparent background to "center" on the total image the "center" of you circle).

Comment: @Larme: neither work. Polar to Rectangular gives straight(ish) lines at the far left and right but an unreadable dip in the middle, and Rectangular to Polar (quite funny) totally inverts the arc so the ends point *upwards* instead of downwards. The problem is it isn't a regular (pixel) distortion to begin with – it's Text On A Path. So any distortion-removing solution *adds* some distortion where there was none.